# display unix variable with dbms_output.put_line

Tags: shell-script, sql, oracle

I have a loop with while that is reading a file and then makes a query of these values.

But when I'm trying to show a message with `dbms_output.put_line` it says :

```
 dbms_output.put_line(henry);
                        *
ERROR at line 15:
ORA-06550: line 15, column 25:
PLS-00201: identifier 'HENRY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 15, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I don't understand this, because if I use the value of the variable in a query, it is ok.